# Typo in the book or am I going crazy?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading about integral bases from Frazer Jarvis' "Algebraic Number Theory", but my question is really about elementary linear algebra. In page 49, author claims the following:
[image]

> I don't think $M'=CM$ is true. I think it should be $M'=MC$. Who's correct, the book or me?

Of course, the conclusion of the theorem follows regardless. But this has been driving me crazy. I know it is a simple linear algebra, but I just want to confirm my doubts :)

**Edit:** As Gerry points out, the screenshot does not capture what the matrix $M$ is. It is defined earlier in the book (in exactly the same way as $M'$ defined, except without the primes):
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1(\omega_1) & \sigma_1(\omega_2) & \cdots & \sigma_1(\omega_n) \\ 
\sigma_2(\omega_1) & \sigma_2(\omega_2) & \cdots & \sigma_2(\omega_n) \\ 
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\sigma_n(\omega_1) & \sigma_n(\omega_2) & \cdots &\sigma_n(\omega_n) 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: It seems you are right, since in $\omega'_i=c_{1i}\omega_1+...+c_{ni}\omega_n$ coefficients represent the $i$th column of $C$.

Comment: Three months ago, I asked a similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897004/deduction-of-usual-cayley-hamilton-theorem-from-determinant-trick). I am very stubborn with checking indices...

Comment: @user35603: Thanks for verifying.

Comment: I don't see where $M$ is defined anywhere.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I am sorry, $M$ is defined earlier in the book. It is exactly the same as $M'$ without the primes… I edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, just to get this out of the unanswered question list, I am posting an answer.

Yes, there is a typo in the book. It should be $M'=MC$. Indeed, $M=(m_{ij})$ where $m_{ij}=\sigma_{i}(\omega_j)$. Then we can compute $(k, i)$-th coefficient of $MC$:
$$
(MC)_{ki} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} m_{kj} c_{ji} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \sigma_{k}(\omega_j)c_{ji} = c_{1i}\sigma_{k}(\omega_1)+c_{2i}\sigma_{k}(\omega_2)+\cdots +c_{ni}\sigma_{k}(\omega_n) = \sigma_{k}(\omega'_{i})=M'_{ki}
$$
Thus, $MC=M'$.